# MinGW pipelining and iterator include

Tags: c++

When I compile this I get about 200 lines of compiler errors using MINGW32..I tried to pipe it to a text file using > but no go.  But is now calling errors on MINGW32 files.

This code is from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855941/necessity-of-writing-print-functions-for-containers)

and an explanation of the code can be found at this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942174/a-generic-print-function)

```
using namespace std;
template <typename Container> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Container& c)  
  {  
  copy(c.begin(), c.end(), ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(os, " "));  
  return os;  
  }
```

Comment: Did you forget the `#include`s? Don't forget that you need `<iostream>`, `<algorithm>`, and `<iterator>`.

Comment: Please pipe the errors to a file with `2>` and post them.

Comment: Sorry basically...I needed to add in <iterator> and use 2> pipe to read the first few compiler messages...Those 2 items got it done.  Thanks...i'll mark it as an answer now so I don't forget.

Comment: Lesson learned: in future please post a **complete**, minimal program that demonstrates the error you are having. If you had posted a complete program, instead of just the program fragment, people would have pointed out the error immediately. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob: You need `<ostream>`, rather.

Comment: @Kerrek. You are right.  Chris -- I have posted your results as a community-wiki answer. Feel free to accept that answer.

Comment: "no go"? What were you trying to accomplish with piping, what was the result, and how did that result differ from what you expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [operator overloading is breaking functions unexpectantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942911/operator-overloading-is-breaking-functions-unexpectantly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't forget to `#include <iterator>`.

2) Capture the compiler's standard error stream instead of its standard output. Use `2>`.