# operator overloading is breaking functions unexpectantly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

Ambiguous overload for `operator<<()` is called when I add the overload function below

```
template <typename Container> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Container& c)  
  {  
  copy(c.begin(), c.end(), ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(os, " "));  
  return os;  
  }
```

the error is called on this function where it uses the `<<`.

```
  void print_list(const list<int>& list_int)
    {
    for (list<int>::const_iterator it = list_int.begin(); it != list_int.end(); it++) cout << *it << " ";
    }
```

Comment: What is the compiler where this doesn't work?

Comment: Breaks in 4.6.1...works in 4.5.2

Comment: I assume you are talking about GCC?

Comment: yep gcc...from MinGW download

Comment: @stack.user.1 : I see you never accept an answer as valid, and this is not nice. If you find the right answer to your question you should accept that answer as valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For reference, if anyone else is looking: http://ideone.com/YlX7q )

Your definition of operator<< can be instantiated as `::operator<<<int>(std::ostream&, const int&)`; this is ambigious with `std::operator<<(std::ostream&, int)`.  Calling the name of the type Container doesn't mean it is a container; overload resolution is done before the definition is instantiated.

Comment: Yes right, it is erroneous to write something like that also if some compiler may allowed it in the past, as i was thinking at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course this cannot work.
You are introducing a templated overload, and the compiler don't know anymore what to use when you use that operator.
Simply you cannot do that.

You can do something like this:

```
template<class T>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass<T>& r);
```

but you cannot do

```
template<class T>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& r);
```

Comment: This was given as an answer on SO here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855941/necessity-of-writing-print-functions-for-containers